# Always shows Login successful, regardless of input. [Android Studio][JAVA]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am learning Android studio, I am trying to create a basic functional Signup and Login page. But regardless of input in Login page it always shows true in if statement (Login Successful), Please tell help me address why is it happening?

**Signup Page Code:**

```
String Username,Email,Password;
Button btn;
EditText uname,email,pw;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pw);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);

    Username = uname.getText().toString();
    Email = email.getText().toString();
    Password = pw.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, Signin.class);
            intent.putExtra("USER", Username);
            intent.putExtra("PASS", Password);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Sign In page Code:**

```
String Signuser, Signpw;
EditText USERNAME, PASSWORD;
TextView showusername;
Button signinbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);



    String SavedUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER");
    String SavedPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("PASS");

    USERNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Userenter);
    PASSWORD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passenter);
    signinbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signinbtn);
    showusername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ShowUser);

    showusername.setText(SavedUser);

    Signuser = USERNAME.getText().toString();
    Signpw = PASSWORD.getText().toString();

     signinbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (Signuser.equals(SavedUser) && Signpw.equals(SavedPass)) {
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "NOPE! DOSENT WORK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You must use camelCases for your variables. It's cause issues. Java and XML as well. It's a basic rule for java...

Comment: Oh okay, I'd look into it. do you think thats causing the issue? rest of code is fine?

Comment: Yeah, and add a log on the clicklistener. You can resolve yourself